# Per-thread initializers for twisted reactor's getThreadPool (or alternative ThreadPool implementation)

Tags: flask, lxml, twisted

**TL;DR:** Is there a way in Twisted to influence thread creation with custom initializers or replace the ThreadPool implementation used by the reactor? Alternatively, can a task be reliably queued to all threads in the reactor thread pool?

Details:

I'm running a Flask application within a Twisted app, using [this pattern](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html):

```
resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), the_app)
site = server.Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(port, site, interface=bind_ip)
```

For XML parsing I use lxml, which occasionally generates an entry to its internal error log, which effectively leaks memory. As I see it there are two ways around this: Periodically clear the error log with `etree.clear_error_log()` or set a global log with `etree.useGlobalPythonLog()`.

Unfortunately each method requires to be run on every single thread, at least once. Therefore I need to have every thread in the ThreadPool run some code once (during initialization) or periodically (conceptually something like "`reactor.callFromEveryThread()`").

Comment: I found a way to monkey-patch the reactor to use a custom ThreadPool, but that is arguably a pretty ugly way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no *good* public interface for accomplishing this.  You should file a feature request in the Twisted issue tracker.  There has been some effort to develop a new threadpool interface.  It is not yet publicly available in any release of Twisted (nor in trunk@HEAD).  Now would be a good time to get new requirements recognized, prior to the initial introduction of the public interface.